# What options do I have for getting back a refund?

Tags: checks

I accidentally overpaid my electric company $55 for the month of August but it turned out that I was moving that month so I cancelled their service. I was told by the electric company that I would get a refund check in the mail. However, it's been 2 months now and they *still* have not sent me anything.

I tried reaching out to the company (which is located in Texas) but they keep hanging up on me. I paid them the amount using a check so I have proof that they owe me the money. But what legal options would I have to get back my money? Is it worth it to file a small claims lawsuit or is it not worth it since I will have to pay legal fees even if I win the case?

Comment: If this were the UK I would say "write a letter before action; then if they don't pay, file a claim in the county court expecting it to be assigned to the small claims track."

Answer (score 3):

Electric power is a highly regulated industry, and you can probably file a complaint with the [Texas Public Utilities Commission](https://www.puc.texas.gov/consumer/complaint/Rights.aspx). The suggest before you [file a complaint](https://www.puc.texas.gov/consumer/complaint/Complaint.aspx), contact them. Rather than calling them on the phone, send them a letter stating why they owe you a refund, and you can add a statement that you expect the refund within 14 days. Also explain your history of trying to get a refund, and you can express the desire to avoid having to file a complaint with the PUC. Send the letter certified, return receipt requested (keep a copy). If for some reason they don't issue the refund, you have the link to the PUC.

Comment: Thank you. That's very insightful. Do you happen to know how the PUC responds to complaints? Will they take action or will they probably just ignore my complaint like the electric company did?

Comment: Minor point: send the letter certified, return receipt requested. This costs much less than registered, and gives all the same legal protection and paper trail. Registered mail is for mailing inherently valuable items, such as negotiable instruments or irreplaceable original documents.